# How to merge list of images using ImageMagic convert tool

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm completely new to ImageMagic. Now I try to follow [this](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-landsat-8/) tutorial. I was able to create three separate images using gdalwarp tool. I did it like so:

```
$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 LC80120542013154LGN00_B4.TIF 4-projected.tif
$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 LC80120542013154LGN00_B3.TIF 3-projected.tif
$ gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 LC80120542013154LGN00_B2.TIF 2-projected.tif
```

So, at this moment I have three separate images - 4-projected.tif, 3-projected.tif and 2-projected.tif and want to combine them, but I do not know how should I interpret this command from the tutorial:

```
$ convert -combine {4,3,2}-projected.tif RGB.tif
```

I'm not sure whether I should run them one by one, or should I use some one-line command. I tried it just as it is, but got the error message:

> Unable to open {4,3,2}-projected.tif image

I also tried to run this command one by one, like:

```
$ convert -combine 4-projected.tif RGB.tif
$ convert -combine 3-projected.tif RGB.tif
$ convert -combine 2-projected.tif RGB.tif
```

But it seems like each following command just rewrites the previous one and instead of combination I just have RGB.tif which is totally identical to 2-projected.tif. So, I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each of those is a single band (greyscale) image and that you want to use `4.tif` as your red channel, `3.tif` as your green and `2.tif` as your blue channel:

```
convert 4.tif 3.tif 2.tif -combine result.tif
```

Also, I would generally recommend lossless compression, else TIF files tend to end up excessively large for no benefit:

```
convert 4.tif 3.tif 2.tif -combine -compress lzw result.tif
```

Comment: By the way, have you ever tried to calculate NDVI, using ImageMagic? At this moment, I tried it this way - `convert NIR.tif RGB.tif -channel RGB  -fx '(u.r-v.r)/(u.r+v.r+0.001)' RGB_ndvi.tif`, but get an error message, that "convert: unable to parse expression `(u.r-1.0*v.r)'". Probably, you know how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I do know NDVI, but I don't have any images to test on. Maybe ask another question supplying a small red and an NIR channel and I'll try. For the moment though in your attempt, you would need to do `-separate` after loading the image to get 3 separate bands/channels before you could use `u` and `v` to refer to two separate images. Or you could use `u.r` to refer to the red channel and `u.g` to refer to the green, or second channel in your image.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I will prepare all images in a minute and prepare a new question.

Comment: I prepared all images and made a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293851/unable-to-create-ndvi-image-using-imagemagick . So, if you have some time, please, have a look. Thanks!