# Unable to create NDVI image using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have four separate images - [2-projected.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pysrd1yjprlc21c/2-projected.tif?dl=0), [3-projected.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pktmu0zhhppwo2p/3-projected.tif?dl=0), [4-projected.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4lo2b5sx7bnruy/4-projected.tif?dl=0) and [5-projected.tif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1soq7ogd9n8y75/5-projected.tif?dl=0). These are four Landsat images. Image 2-projected.tif corresponds to blue channel, image 3-projected.tif - to green channel, image 4-projected.tif - to red channel, and 5-projected.tif - to infrared. Now I want to create NDVI image. To do this, I first create a combined RGB image, using ImageMagic:

```
$ convert 4-projected.tif 3-projected.tif 2-projected.tif -combine RGB.tif
```

So far, so good. And then I try to follow a command from [this](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2005168-Aerial-Search-Recovery) tutorial, which is supposed to create NDVI image. I do it like so:

```
$ convert 5-projected.tif RGB.tif -channel RGB -fx '(u.r-v.r)/(u.r+v.r+0.001)' -normalize NDVI.tif
```

But as a result, I get these error messages:

> convert: unable to parse expression `(u.r-1.0*v.r)' @ error/fx.c/FxGetSymbol/183
>   1.
>   convert: divide by zero`'(u.r-1.0*v.r)/(u.r+v.r+0.001)'' @ error/fx.c/FxEvaluat
>   eSubexpression/2159.

I'm not sure how can I fix it.

Comment: BTW, NDVI formula in theory looks like `(NIR-VIS)/(NIR+VIS)` (according to wikipedia) and I've seen some other ImageMagic commands to create NDVI. For example, in this article - http://blog.sogeo.services/blog/2014/09/22/ndvi-orthofotos.html - they calculate it like `-fx '(u.r - u.g) / (u.r + u.g + 0.001)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two bands of interest are the `red` and the `NIR` and the formula for NDVI is:

```
NDVI = (NIR-red)/(NIR+red)
```

---

You have two options. First off, if you have the red and the NIR in two separate, single channel images, you can do:

```
convert red.tif NIR.tif -fx '(u.r-v.r)/(u.r+v.r+0.001)' -normalize -compress lzw NDVI.tif
```

Here, I am using `u.r` to refer to the first channel of the first image and `v.r` to refer to the first channel of the second image.

[image]

---

Alternatively, if the red and NIR are the first two channels in an RGB image (i.e. **ImageMagick** would call them the red and green channels):

```
convert RGB.tif -fx '(u.r-u.g)/(u.r+u.g+0.001)' -normalize -compress lzw NDVI.tif
```

Here I am using `u.r` to refer to the first channel of the first image and `u.g` to refer to the second channel of the first image.

---

The `-fx` method is extremely powerful, but notoriously slow. This method below should give you the same answer, but I have not checked it too thoroughly:

```
convert 4-projected.tif -write MPC:red +delete           \
        5-projected.tif -write MPC:NIR +delete           \
       \( mpc:red mpc:NIR -evaluate-sequence subtract \) \
       \( mpc:red mpc:NIR -evaluate-sequence add      \) \
       -evaluate-sequence divide -normalize -compress lzw NDVI.tif
```

---

If you want to colourise the image with false colour, you could generate a Colour Lookup Table (CLUT) and map the grayscale values in the NDVI image to those colours. So, let's say you wanted to map the darkest blacks in your NDVI image to black, the quite dark values to red, the quite bright values to orange and the very brightest values to green, you could make a CLUT like this:

```
convert xc:black xc:red xc:orange xc:lime +append clut.png
```

[image]

and apply it the greyscale result from above like this:

```
convert NDVI.tif -normalize clut.png -clut falsecolour.jpg
```

[image]

If you want to make the orange and green tones *longer* (more prevalent), you can alter their lengths to make them longer in the CLUT:

```
convert -size 30x1 xc:black -size 40x1 xc:red -size 80x1 xc:orange -size 100x1 xc:lime +append clut.png
```

[image]

Then re-apply the CLUT:

```
convert NDVI.tif -normalize clut.png -clut result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a second!

Comment: I am going to add a faster method in a minute - hang on.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I'm still getting this "Unable to parse (u.r-1.0*u.g)" error message. It seems like this error does not even relate to the task itself

Comment: You are not on Windows are you? If you are, use double quotes instead of single quotes around the `-fx` expression.

Comment: You are right! The whole problem was in single quotes! Many thanks for a great answer!

Comment: BTW. I also tried your last command and get this error message - "unable to open image `\(`. So, on Windows again there is some trouble, but now with `\(` combination.

Comment: On Windows, simply omit the backslash that Unix needs before opening and closing parentheses. So `\(` becomes `(` and `\)` becomes `)`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works and I got a picture exactly like yours, though, I wonder why there is so much black. In practice NDVI images look something like - http://imgur.com/a/bPJx4

Comment: Mmm.. an NDVI image is just a ratio and as such it is a single band so it must be grey - having no red, green and blue channels. Also, there appears to be a body of water in the lower-left quadrant and that will not reflect NIR at all so it should be pure black not white. Also, the NDVI produced by my calculation shows up very bright (white) indicating strong vegetation growth along the banks of the water which is also likely to be correct. Obviously I don't know your image area or your ground truth, and I may be wrong...

Comment: Thank you, Mark! I guess you are right, and I just need some additional transformation before publishing the image.

Comment: Judging by this - http://www.geog2.com/NDVI-Information.html - there are two types of NDVI - grayscale (just like you said) and colorized. I wish I knew how to move from one to another, using ImageMagic, if it is possible :)

Comment: I tried some false-colouring as per the link you gave - please look again.

Comment: Wondreful solution! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello, Mark! Sorry for bothering once again. I have a question and probably you know the answer. What I want to achieve is to make black margins (that do not belong to the map itself) completely transparent. If I use some tools like gdalwarp and associate black color with transparency, then in case of grayscale NDVI I get almost completely transparent image - the inside part, or the map, also becomes transparent, because it contains a lot of black color. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Initial images from which the resulting NDVI image is made do not contain so much black color, so is it possible to somehow make them transparent in advance and then when making NDVI image just persist initial transparent regions?

Comment: Try applying the following to one of your output images to make the borders transparent... `convert NDVI.tif -fill none -fuzz 2% -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' output.tif`

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a second!

Comment: I checked it against the grayscale NDVI.tif and got the same result as with gdalwarp tool - the internals of the map also became completely transparent

Comment: But what if I apply this command to 4_projected.tif and 5_projected.tif before making the NDVI.tif? Will the command that creates NDVI.tif image preserve transparent regions?

Comment: Ok, you can extract the alpha from one of your original images into `alpha.pgm` like this: `convert someOriginalImage.tif -fill none -fuzz 2% -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -alpha extract alpha.pgm`. Then you can apply that to an NDVI image later like this: `convert NDVI.tif alpha.pgm -compose copyalpha -composite FinalResult.tif`

Comment: It looks fantastic! I will check now!

Comment: By the way, addind a transparency mask works just perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Hello, Mark! I guess in the first formula it should be `(v.r-u.r)/(u.r+v.r+0.001)`, because u refers to red.tif and v - to NIR.tif and according to the formula `NDVI = (NIR-red)/(NIR+red)`